# Hide Navbar in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, navbar, hide

I tried everything to hide the Navbar each time a user click on a link.

Hope for help. Thanks everyone. I use vue.js

U got any ideas?

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container-button">
       <button class="button" @click="Navbar = !Navbar">Menu</button>
    </div>
   <div>
        <MainMenu v-if="Navbar" class="menu-Display"> </MainMenu>
   </div>
```

**JS**

```
import Navbar-Menu from "@*/MainMenu.vue"

export default {
  name: "Header",
  components: {
    MainMenu
  },

  data() {
    return {
      Navbar: false
    }

  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-Display {
        top: 50px;
        right: 10px;
        bottom: 30px;
        width:100px;
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to hide the navbar, or the navbar menu?

Your code seems to have an error: `import Navbar-Menu from "@*/MainMenu.vue"` should be `import MainMenu from "@*/MainMenu.vue"`, otherwise it doesn't get registered in your components.

For the rest, I see no errors, so maybe you could show more of the html template?

Comment: You right. I fixed: import MainMenu from "@*/MainMenu.vue" 
Thank you. I want hide the Navbar menu. Thats it, the rest is just <div class="header">

I want each user clicks on a link in the navbar the user move to the site and the navbar is not show again, until a user is clicking on the navbar button.